# How to change x-axis date format dynamically in c3js chart?

Tags: javascript, php, c3.js

I have a line chart with dynamic data make by c3js chart library.

In that chart, I already show data depend on date with timeseries. Here is the sample of chart.
[image: sample chart]

Now I add three button to show data in chart by `day`,`month` and `year`. When I click `day` button, I want to show data only day by day. And the `year` and `month` button are also too.

The main point is, I want to change x-axis date format dynamically when I click `day`, `month` and `year` button.

So I query data from database for each day, month and year. But the problem is, when I show data in chart, I need to change date format dynamically in x-axis. So, I try like this,

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btn_day'])) {
     $sql = "......."
     $query = ........;
     //query data day by day just like DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d') as date
     .
     $format = '%d';
}elseif(isset($_POST['btn_month'])) {
     $sql = "......."
     $query = ........;
     //query data for each month just like DATE_FORMAT(date, '%M') as date
     .
     $format = '%m';
}elseif(isset($_POST['btn_year'])) {
     $sql = "......."
     $query = ........;
     //query data for each year just like DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y') as date
     .
     $format = '%Y';
}else {
     $sql = "......."
     $query = ........;
     .
     .
     $format = '%Y-%m-%d';
}
?>
<script>
        var f = <?php echo "'".$format."'"?>; //'%Y-%m-%d'
        console.log(f);
        var chart = c3.generate({
            bindto: '#chart',
            data: {
                x: 'date',
                json:<?php echo json_encode($data);?>,
                mimeType: 'json',
                keys: {
                    x: 'date',
                    value:  <?php echo json_encode($names)?>
                },
                type: 'line',
            },
            axis: {
                x: {
                    type: 'timeseries',
                    tick:{
                        format: function(f){
                                if(f == "%d"){
                                    return d3.getDay();
                                }else if(f == "%m"){
                                    return d3.getMonth();
                                }else if(f == "%Y"){
                                    return d3.getFullYear();
                                }else{
                                    return '%Y-%m-%d';
                                }
                        },
                        rotate: 75,
                    }
                }
            },          

        });
</script>
```

But I don't get correct result in chart. I know I was wrong in this part,

```
tick:{
    format: function(f){
        if(f == "%d"){
            return d3.getDay();
        }else if(f == "%m"){
            return d3.getMonth();
        }else if(f == "%Y"){
            return d3.getFullYear();
        }else{
            return '%Y-%m-%d';
        }
    },
    rotate: 75,
}
```

But I don't know how can I change x-axis date format dynamically. I already try a lot of way but I can't get correct result.

I very appreciate for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

d3 doesn't have getDay() / getMonth() / getFullYear() functions, what you need (if f exists) is

```
d3.time.format(f)
```

See https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting

(Moreover, you're not really changing the formatting dynamically as far as the chart is concerned, you're generating a new c3 chart each time, though that's probably just semantics.)

Comment: So, you mean is , If I need to change time format, I need to make new chart. Right?

Comment: in "format: function(f)", f will be a Date not your php format string. This Date you can apply getDay(), getMonth() to but you'll need to access the php format string with a php declaration (php's not my strong point). As a separate point, the format string syntax you use ("%d", %m", and "%Y") can be used with d3.time.format() as an alternative way to generate date parts for the tick labels. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Can you show me sample code please? Because when I try as you said, I get only like this '%Y-%m-%d'. I'm stuck in this error.

Comment: Thank you for `d3.time.format(f)`. Now I can find the way.

Comment: One other thing that can catch people out (i.e. me when I first used it) is the usage is `d3.time.format(your_format)(your_date)` . Often best to set `var format = d3.time.format(your_format)` and then call it as `var return format(your_date)` to avoid that confusion.